# Periodicity in modulos of the form $10^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Several months ago, I found a statement on the web that the modulus $10^k$ has a period of $$\text{lcm}(\Phi(2^k),\Phi(5^k))$$

where $\Phi$ is the euler totient function. In other words, if

$$p \equiv k \mod(\text{lcm}(\Phi(2^k),\Phi(5^k)))$$

then

$$a^k \equiv a^{p} \mod(10^k)$$

This seems to hold true for a few values that I tried, but are there any restrictions of $k$ or $a$? Does something similar hold for any modulus?

This also seems quite similar to euler's theorem. Is there any connection between the two?

Comment: Lookup: multiplicative group of modulo n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a^p\equiv a^q\pmod m$ with $a$ coprime to $m$ (we can relax this later) and denote by $\mathrm{ord}_m(a)$ the least exponent $d>0$ such that $a^d\equiv 1\pmod m$. It is not hard to show that $\mathrm{ord}_m(a)$ must divide $p-q$. We can similarly show that $\mathrm{ord}_m(a)\mid \varphi(m)$.

Now look at what you have: by hypothesis, $\mathrm{lcm}(\varphi(2^k), \varphi(5^k))\mid p-q$, so $\mathrm{ord}_{2^k}(a)\mid\varphi(2^k)\mid p-q$ and $\mathrm{ord}_{5^k}(a)\mid\varphi(5^k)\mid p-q$. This shows $a^{p-q}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^k}$ and $a^{p-q}\equiv 1\pmod{5^k}$ and, by the chinese remainder theorem, we are set.

---

Of course, there is nothing special about $10$, $2$ or $5$. Let $m=uv$ with $u$ and $v$ coprime and $b$ coprime to $m$.

If $\mathrm{lcm}(\varphi(u),\varphi(v))\mid d$, then both $b^{d}\equiv 1\pmod u$ and $b^{d}\equiv 1\pmod v$ are true, so $b^{d}\equiv 1\pmod {uv}$.

Comment: How did you arrive at $$a^{p-q}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^k}$$ and $$a^{p-q}\equiv 1\pmod{5^k}$$ from $$\mathrm{ord}_{2^k}(a)\mid\varphi(2^k)\mid p-q$$ and $$\mathrm{ord}_{5^k}(a)\mid\varphi(5^k)\mid p-q$$?

Comment: If $\mathrm{ord}_m(a)\mid t$, then $t=k\,\mathrm{ord}_m(a)$. Therefore, $a^t\equiv\left(a^{\mathrm{ord}_{m}(a)}\right)^k\equiv 1\pmod m$. The analysis of the [$\mathrm{ord}$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) is very important and takes up the entire third section of the Disquisitiones. It introduces us a very important notion, the notion of a [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n). You can read a quick treatment [here](http://ae.hc.cust.edu.tw/new_website/attachments/article/244/Lecture%209_primitive%20Roots%20.pdf).